# Does my mechanical room need ventilation to the exterior?

Tags: vent, boiler

Sorry for the confusing post. I don’t have a manual as the prior owner didn’t have it. If I understand correctly, a boiler room in a residential home requires a vent for fresh air. This boiler room previously had 2 vents on the interior wall. As these two vents were opened and leading to the home, you can hear the boiler and water tank noises loudly if in the basement. As part of the remodeling, these two vents were removed and we are considering placing a vent right above the pipe in the photo I have shown. I’m asking if there is a safety concern with having a vent leading to outside.

[image][image]

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. If your mechanical equipment requires makeup air (which is a safety issue and often mandated by code), your owners manuals should indicate this. If you're asking about sound, no. That won't do anything. The idea is almost comical that sound would obediently jump though a hole like that. Please [revise](https://diy.stackexchange.com/posts/174791/edit) to make it more apparent what you're asking.

Comment: I linked you to the edit feature. Please use it. New information doesn't belong in a comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Air is a thing.  (This took humanity millenia to figure this out; we figured out industrial use of fire soon after, and then, aviation!) You can even put air in a bag, that's what a bag of air is!

Fire involves fuel (you bring) and air (that is just around).  Your furnace and water heater burn a fuel, and get air *from somewhere*.  **Where they get it is very important**!    Some furnaces use "direct vent", meaning they bring in fresh air from outside, just for their own use, using a double exhaust pipe.  Those you don't need to worry about.   However most simply grab air that is in the room, *and that's a problem*.

For every bagful of air that the furnace or water heater send up the stack, *a replacement bagful of air has to come into the house somehow*.   Back in the day, houses were very leaky, and that wasn't a problem, but modern houses can be tight enough to make that a problem.

Regardless, one problem is the replacement air leaking into the house is cold and dry (or hot and wet), causing drafts and forcing the heater and humidifier (or A/C) to work all that much harder.

Ventilating the equipment room would be a step in the right direction, becuase it would provide combustion air for them without pulling drafts in the rest of the house. You may also want to insulate this room from the house -- but not too much.... on a very cold day, that could be a lot of cold air.  You have to make sure the water pipes don't freeze!

In an ideal world, you have direct venting, where the outside draw air goes directly (and only) to the burners.

Answer (score 0):

Your appliance's that have combustion need to be able to draw air from outside the room that they are housed in.

If you have eliminated the ones that were there and you do not want  one that allow noise into the living space then

*yes the contractor who said to install one in the exterior wall is correct*.

Comment: Repeating in a different  way ; The gas ( and oil) appliances must have free access to combustion air. It is not "ventilation"  and any sound factor is incidental.

Comment: Thank you both for the response.  I have added another photo showing that my boiler and water heater are connected to a chimney.  I’m not too familiar with combustion air as I’m a first time homeowner but doesn’t the chimney play a role for combustion air.  Or regardless of the chimney, I need a exterior “vent” to get fresh or make up air into the boiler room.

Comment: Yes, install a vent in the exterior wall. The chimney is how the carbon monoxide gets out, but you still need an air inlet, because they need a source of oxygen.

As a bonus, if you don't have an air inlet, you can get a backdraft going on. Let's say you have a kitchen fan going, sucking air out of the house. If there are no other vents, it can end up sucking air in through the chimney, bringing carbon monoxide with it.